# Como eu faço para levar no header location apenas o nome do usuário

Tags: php, html

A minha tela de login vai levar para login_proc.php que inicia a sessão. Eu quero passar para a tela reserva.php o nome do usuário. Como fazer isso passando no header ou de outra maneira. Além disso, como faço para pegar o valor que passar no reserva.php?

```
<?php
// Iniciar a $_SESSION
session_start();

require_once "conexao.php";


$usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'usuario_nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($banco, $usuario);
$senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "SELECT id_usuario, usuario_nome, senha FROM usuario WHERE usuario_nome = '$usuario'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($banco, $sql);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);


@header ("location:reserva.php?usuario=$usuario");
```

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja, e se é o correto, mas para fazer o que quer, tente assim: `@header("location:reserva.php?usuario=" . $usuario);` ou `@header("location:reserva.php?usuario={$usuario}");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passa pela variavel global $_SESSION. Ela é responsável por armazenar as informações da sessão.

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($banco, $sql);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

$_SESSION['userId'] = $registro['id_usuario'];
$_SESSION['userName'] = $registro['usuario_nome'];


@header ("location:reserva.php");
```

Depois basta acessar a $_SESSION e fazer o que deseja. Ela é acessível em qualquer lugar da aplicação:

```
$userName = $_SESSION['userName'];
```

Comment: Por que utilizar o `@` em `@header`?

Comment: @Woss só a AP vai poder responder :P, o vaz só ajustou para sessões.

Comment: Exatamente, só copiei o código e adicionei a sessão. Mas é um ponto interessante, eu nem tinha reparado

Answer (score -1):

Se "reserva.php" for apenas para regra de negócio você pode usar $_SESSION para armazenar o conteúdo que deseja, caso seja o retorno direto de uma página que terá HTML renderizado você pode fazer:

```
echo json_encode(['usuario' =>  $usuario]);
```

A solução depende de como está implementada a página de retorno.